# How to change the endpoints of a picture in Latex but still keep the same length?

Tags: graphics, tables, boxplot

I am trying to make a table in LaTeX with 2 columns and 10 rows. Each row represents a different city and each column will represent a parameter. 
In each column I want to draw the mean and the quantiles of the parameter (of the MCMC draws).

This code makes a boxplot

```
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand{\boxplot}[5]{
\begin{picture}(100, 7)
\put(#1, 2){\line(0, 1){4}}
\put(#1, 4){\line(1, 0){#2}}
\put(#3, 4){\circle*{3}}
\put(#3, 4){\line(1, 0){#4}}
\put(#5, 2){\line(0, 1){4}}
\put(50, 3){\line(0, 1){4}}
\end{picture}
}
```

and this is an example for making the table.

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}
\noindent
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{c r  @{} c }
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Flight} \\\hline

Rank & Change  & 50\% \\
\hline
1 & flight2reuse, & \boxplot{17.700000}{3.500000}{21.200000}{12.100000}{33.300000} \\
2 & improveteam, & \boxplot{20.800000}{4.500000}{25.300000}{9.100000}{34.400000} \\
2 & none, & \boxplot{20.100000}{6.200000}{26.300000}{11.800000}{38.100000} \\
3 & reducefunc, & \boxplot{18.700000}{8.500000}{27.200000}{11.000000}{38.200000} \\
3 & improveprecflex, & \boxplot{22.400000}{7.700000}{30.100000}{11.800000}{41.900000} \\
3 & flight4reuse, & \boxplot{23.000000}{7.200000}{30.200000}{12.400000}{42.600000} \\
4 & relaxschedule, & \boxplot{21.000000}{7.500000}{28.500000}{18.400000}{46.900000} \\
4 & archriskresl, & \boxplot{21.900000}{7.900000}{29.800000}{10.200000}{40.000000} \\
5 & improvepmat, & \boxplot{21.200000}{10.000000}{31.200000}{15.100000}{46.300000} \\
6 & flight3reuse, & \boxplot{23.800000}{10.600000}{34.400000}{10.400000}{44.800000} \\
7 & reducequality, & \boxplot{30.600000}{5.500000}{36.100000}{11.400000}{47.500000} \\
8 & improvepcap, & \boxplot{29.600000}{9.800000}{39.400000}{8.100000}{47.500000} \\
9 & improvetooltechplat, & \boxplot{40.800000}{13.000000}{53.800000}{18.400000}{72.200000} \\
10& flight1reuse, & \boxplot{31.400000}{35.500000}{66.900000}{14.700000}{81.600000} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that the parameters I have to use are between -1 and 1 (not like in this example from 0 to 100)
I have tried adding a second argument to `\begin{picture}`

```
\begin{picture}(100, 7)(-50,0)
```

this means that the start (at the lower left side) is at (-50,0) and the end is at (50,7) in the upper right corner.
This unfortunately makes my parameters almost invisible.
On the other hand if I change it to

```
 \begin{picture}(2, 7)(-1,0)
```

I have the same problem.
I want to somehow have a command like `\begin{picture}(100, 7)(-1,0)(1,7)`
which would mean that the length is 100mm, it starts at (-1,0) and ends at (1,7).In that case my parameters would look normal. I have tried different ways but couldn't come up with an answer.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\setlength\unitlength{50mm}
```

so that there is 100mm between `(-1,0)` and `(1,0)`.